# How do i put a word filter on my website chat?

Tags: chat

I want to put a filter on the chatroom of my website that will just filter some words (eg: If someone types 'Hello' it will be filtered to 'HEEY')...that's just an example. But how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a very vague question: you'll be much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more details. Most importantly: what programming language or framework are you using to create your chatroom? Also, as a general rule, you are more likely to get answers (and upvotes) if you can provide some sample code that illustrates what you've already tried to do, explain the behavior you're seeing, and explain how it differs from the behavior you want to see. That won't apply in all cases, but the more effort you demonstrate, the more likely you'll get a response.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the language you have coded your chatroom in.

Assuming it is PHP, just read the text and do a `str_replace()` function.

For more info, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php